# if a=2 and b=3 then how a && b = 3 rather than true?

Tags: javascript

There is one interview question below. 
The logical AND of two truths should be true. But the output is 3. Why?

```js
var a = 2;
var b = 3;

var c = a && b; // value of c = 3

console.log(c);
```

Comment: `a` is truthy, so it evaluates to the second operand.

Comment: Because JavaScript `&&` and `||` don't work the same way they do in languages like C and Java. They use fall-through/short circuit logic.

Comment: You shouldn't assume the operators such as `&&` in any programming language have anything to do with "logical AND". You should find out what they are defined to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

If you use && with non-boolean values, it returns the first element if it can be converted to false. If it cannot converted to false, it returns second element

Answer (score 0):

Returns a if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns b.